# Set mule http.request from properties

Tags: mule

I have a `<https:outbound-endpoint>`with host, port & path etc set. I need to set various other parameters like username and password that are needed for the path and was trying to do this like so with a message properties transformer

```
<message-properties-transformer>
                <add-message-property key="Username" value="admin*^!"/>
                <add-message-property key="Password" value="test*^!""/>
             </message-properties-transformer>
```

So when I post to an endpoint the http.request includes the url like with full path set

https://http.testserver1:5555/Path?Username=admin&Password=test

But it doesn't work. It cannot pick up the username and password.
I also tried the annotation `<set-property propertyName>`to no avail.

How could I go about this? It doesn't allow me to set the full path due to illegal characters

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing? Is it "it cannot pick up the username and password" or "it doesn't allow me to set the full path due to illegal characters"?? Because they both are separate issues.

Comment: It cannot pick up the username and password. Not being allowed to set the full path is why i've gone about using a message-properties-transformer

Comment: How do you pick up the username and password?

You cannot use `message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.username` since you're using message-property. Therefore you have to use `message.inboundProperties.username` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to set the user and pass using a <message-properties-transformer> shown above, I thought I could do it this way